# Class method that returns object and transfers ownership

Tags: objective-c

**[This is memory management clarification/question]**

- I have a class method that returns an NSMutableArray*.
- I want the caller to own it and have to call release.
- I don't want to use AutoRelease because I want it freed from memory as soon as caller is done.

Is this ok to do as long as I start the name with new or alloc, correct?

e.g.

```
+ (NSMutableArray*) newArrayFromDB
{
  NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  //stuff to populate array
  return myArray;
}
```

Then the caller will call with:

```
 NSMutableArray* test = [ThatClass newArrayFromDB];
  //use test
  [test release];
```

The Static Analyzer seems to think it is ok...but I wanted a second opinion...

Thanks for any feedback....

Comment: Why do you want this? What makes this case that special?

Comment: I did not realize (as David pointed out) that the default autorelease pool was drained every time through the main loop.  I mistakenly thought it was not drained until the pool itself went out of scope.  I am now happily returning an Autoreleased NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, what you're doing is correct - you're following rules in the [object ownership policy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1)  correctly.

The only point I might question is `I don't want to use AutoRelease because I want it freed from memory as soon as caller is done`. The default autorelease pool is drained every time through the main run loop, so in most cases the memory will be released soon anyway. And, if the caller needs to force a release sooner, it can always allocate/drain an autorelease pool manually. Of course, one approach would be to create two convenience methods `+ newArrayFromDB:` and `+arrayFromDB`; one that autoreleases and one that doesn't.

Comment: I did not realize the autorelease pool was drained everytime through the main runloop - that makes a lot of sense.  I think I am going to switch to returning an autoreleased array.  Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is the way to do it.

I would probably use the word "create" to indicate that the caller has ownership, but new is alright too i guess.

---

p.s. using allocWithZone:NULL is a touch faster than alloc, if you want to scrape a little more speed.

Comment: Using `new*` instead of `create*` conforms to the memory management rules.